# how do I get the sitecore item Published Date?

Tags: date, publish, sitecore

Ho do I get the published date of a sitecore item? There are fields like `_______created` and `___updated` but couldn't find anything for published date. I tried the following:

```cs
Sitecore.Context.Item.Publishing.PublishDate
```

But this only gives me date if I explicitly set it from the Content Editor. Basically I just want to print out the date the item was published.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't get a published date. We have to implement a custom way to track when items are published.

Answer (score 3):

Try '`__publish`' and '`__unpublish`' for Publish Date and Unpublished Date accordingly.

Comment: Nope, don't get anything with that. Isn't it the same as using "Sitecore.Context.Item.Publishing.PublishDate"? Only contains a value if I set it explicitly.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's the way it works. If you want to obtain ALL fields disregarding if it has value or not, just call item.Fields.ReadAll() for that item before reading the fields.

Comment: '__publish' and '__unpublish' fields are for different purpose: to set timeframe when item is allowed to be published. It should not be used to track published date/time.